# How to distinguish between natural and unnatural equivalences of categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, functoriality

Some equivalences of categories are constructed by explicitly giving a pair of functors that are inverses up to isomorphism. For example, the equivalence between CRing^op and affine schemes is given by the pair (Spec, GlobalSections). I'd say these are "natural", since no choices are made.

Another equivalence of categories is between finite dimensional vector spaces and the category consisting of one vector space of each dimension. The functor in one direction is just the inclusion, but the inverse requires making a bunch of choices. I'd say this is "unnatural".

But my definitions of "natural" and "unnatural" aren't precise. I suppose one of the triumphs of category theory has been the ability to make precise the definition of natural in some contexts. So my question is: how can I make this precise?

Answer (score 14):

You could try to make it precise by asking what equivalences remain if you deprive yourself of the axiom of choice.  The point, I think, is that there are two ways to define an equivalence of categories:

1. A functor *F*: **C** --> **D** is a *strong equivalence* if there exist a functor *G*: **D** --> **C** and isomorphisms 1 --> *GF*, *FG*--> 1.
2. A functor *F*: **C** --> **D** is a *weak equivalence* if it is full, faithful and essentially surjective on objects.

To prove that every strong equivalence is weak is straightforward and does not require any kind of choices to be made.  But to prove that every weak equivalence is strong, you have to choose for each object *D* of **D** an object *C* of **C** such that *F(C)* is isomorphic to *D*.  That requires a strong form of the axiom of choice: you're making as many choices as there are objects of **D**.

So, if you work in a logical setup where you have no axiom of choice, or only a weak form of it, then some categories that were previously equivalent will no longer be equivalent.  For example, most categories will not be equivalent to their skeleton.  (You mentioned this in the case of finite-dimensional vector spaces.)  Perhaps you could define the *natural* equivalences to be those that continue to be equivalences in this world without choice.

Comment: In fact, in the absence of choice, most categories will not even HAVE a skeleton.

Comment: Suppose I don't want to deny the axiom of choice. Then is there some extra property or structure that the strong equivalence will have that the weak one won't? The example I'm having in mind is the isomorphism from a fin. dim. vector space to it's double dual. These isomorphisms have the nice property of also being natural transforms between two functors. The isomorphism from a vector space to it's single dual probably doesn't have this property, but I'm not interested in proving that. I want a positive test so I can point to a pair of functors and say they give a strong equivalence. 

Comment: How do you make a natural transformation between a covariant and a contravariant functor?

Comment: You don't. I'm saying maybe there is a covariant functor out there that on objects takes vector spaces to their single dual (probably not, but i don't know how to prove that). The map from a vector space to its double dual doesn't make explicit mention of functors, but here there is an obvious covariant functor that is the double dual on objects.

Comment: Dinakar, I wonder if you're getting confused between some different concepts here.  It's a matter of fact that the double dual functor from Vect to Vect is isomorphic (=naturally isomorphic) to the identity functor.  But that has little to do with the distinction between "natural" and "unnatural", or "strong" and "weak", equivalences of categories.  

Comment: What I mean is the following. We can define the double dual of a vector space without mentioning functors. We can define the map from a vector space to its double dual without mentioning functors. And we can do this for all vector spaces at the same time. Now to say it is natural, we're saying that this collection of maps are actually a natural transformation between two functors. So our maps have been promoted to natural transformations because the identity and double dual operator have been promoted to functors.

Comment: On the other hand, you can try and do the same thing with the single dual. By making a lot of choices, you can get maps from each finite dimensional vector space to its single dual. But there is no obvious way to promote this single dual operator to a covariant functor in such a way that the collection of maps we have chosen will give a natural transformation. What I'm asking is whether there is an analogous way to express the difference between strong and weak equivalence? Is there some structure you can add to test whether a given pair of inverse functors is strong equivalence?

Comment: The single dual map is not covariant...

Answer (score 4):

On the other hand to Tom's answer, the distinction between strong and weak equivalences disappears if you use [anafunctors](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/anafunctor) instead of functors, which is arguably the "right" way to do category theory in the absence of choice.  Someone who takes this point of view would argue that the inverse (ana)functor from FDVect to the category of (say) Euclidean spaces actually *doesn't* involve any unnatural choices, because every time you have to choose something, all of the things you have to choose from are uniquely canonically isomorphic.

It's precisely analogous to how if a category C has binary products, you need to make a bunch of "choices" to define a product functor C × C → C, but in each case the "category of possible choices" is contractible and so you aren't really making any "contentful" choices at all.  And actually, depending on what foundational axiom system you use, your example of a "natural" equivalence might actually involve this sort of "contentless" choice as well.  The underying space of Spec R is some subset of P(R) (the prime ideals), but in a categorical set theory like ETCS, the power-object P(R) is only characterized up to isomorphism.

Thus, someone who takes this point of view might claim that the distinction you want to draw is actually an illusory one.